# CyanogenMod error signing school Google account on the Oneplus One

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-account, oneplus-one

Phone: `OnePlus One`
OS: Cyanogen OS `12.1.1-YOG7DAS2K1` 
Andorid Version: `5.1.1`

I recently purchased the Oneplus One used. I love everything about the phone and OS,  however I cannot seem to sign into my school's Google account (a large portion of the reason I bought the phone at all).  I searched XDA and here for an answer to this question and could not find an answer. !

I tried to log in as explained [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/314222-adding-school-email-gmail-app-advanced-options.html) but there is no 'sign-in through browser' option. I'm truly at a loss as for what to do.

I've also now tried the unlock captcha link (suggestion found [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/MYMPboXWO_I)) and the method of importing a specific certificate found here on StackExchange (I am looking for the link again).
Please note, I have already talked to my IT department and they say that the account has mobile access and that there shouldn't be any problems.

*edit* After the update to Cyanogen OS 13 everything is gravy.

Comment: What error do you receive when you try to sign in to the account?

Comment: It states _"Cannot Connect to sso.chemekta.edu"_ which is the authentication server.

Comment: [Failure to Authenticate Images](https://goo.gl/photos/U81jeUYoBnbt886k6)

Comment: Are you using two-step verification on your account?

Comment: Nope :[ It is off.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. You could try resetting the phone I suppose but this will wipe all data and I suspect that this is a Google issue. In that case, maybe contact Google Support? Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: If nothing works I will try to factory reset and post the results of course.